# Django reverse error when passing additional variable

Tags: django

I am attempting to pass variables through different django views.

The error I am getting is:

```
Reverse for 'download_file' with keyword arguments '{'path_id': '19', 'filename': 'TESTCE-DCNCE-01.conf'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P<filename>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

I have this working code:

This is my view.py

```
def report(request, pk_test):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    path_id = str(order.id)
    outpath = 'orchestration/outputs/' + str(order.id)
    files_configs = glob.glob(outpath + '/*.conf', recursive=True)
    files = []
    for each_file in files_configs:
        head, tail = path.split(each_file)
        files.append(tail)

    context = {
        'order': order,
        'files_configs': files,
        'path_id': path_id,
    }
return render(request, 'orchestration/report.html', context)
```

Here is my report.html:

```
  {% for each_files_configs in files_configs %}
    <p></p>
    <a href="{% url 'download_file' filename=each_files_configs %}">{{ each_files_configs }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is my views.py, which is linked to the href:

```
def download_file(request, filename=''):
    if filename != '':
```

When I run the code like ths, it works fine. If I then add the additional parameter 'path_id' as below, I get a reverse error. Surely path_id is no different from passing in filename?

```
  {% for each_files_configs in files_configs %}
    <p></p>
    <a href="{% url 'download_file' path_id=path_id filename=each_files_configs %}">{{ each_files_configs }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is my views.py, which is linked to the href:

```
def download_file(request, path_id='', filename=''):
    if filename != '':
```

Comment: You need to add this pattern to your `urls.py` file - so you have both `/download/<filename>/` and `/download/<path_id>/<filename>/` - they can use the same view as each other

Comment: Yep, that worked thanks. This thing is a massive jigsaw!